# Relation between a page Click-Through Rate and the average number of clicks necessary to reach it from any other page of the site

Tags: links, semantic-web, ctr

In *Search Engine Optimization: Comparison of Link Building and Social Sharing* (Sonya Zhang & Neal Cabage, 2016) I found a troubling *id est* relation:

> Using well-structured pages including sections and categories, self-documenting semantic URLs, well-selected internal linking and keywords, and effective navigation **can get a user to any page of the site with fewer clicks, i.e., high click-through rates** (CTRs).

This point is not further developed in the rest of the paper, and my question is: In which way the fact that a page is accessible in few clicks is equivalent to the page having a high CTR ?

Comment: My question would be "click through from what?"   CTR is a measure of how many users click from the starting point to the destination.   Maybe they are talking about the home page as the starting point and the content the user is looking for as the destination?

Comment: Oh it makes sense. Your interpretation does make me gain some intuition about this, thanks !